# Open recent fragment Bottom Navigation Activity

Tags: android

I have a bottom activity with 3 menus (Fragment). Home , News and Settings. In Setting there is another menus (ListView) . Profil, About and Contact Us.

If you click Profil it will open new activity (Profil.Class) .

My question is how can I open recent tab (Setting), because now if I click back button and back arrow from toolbar it will open My bottom activity with `home fragment` instead of s`ettings framgent`. I trying to send `putExtra();` from my `SettingFragment`  but its not working . how can I achieve that?

So here is my MainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = getSupportActionBar();
    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);


    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Integer tabtoOpen = intent.getIntExtra("Tab",0);
    Log.d("TABB", tabtoOpen.toString());

    if(tabtoOpen == 0){
        fragment = new MainFragment();
    }else if(tabtoOpen == 1){
        fragment =  new NewsFragment();
    }else if(tabtoOpen == 2){
        fragment =  new SettingsFragment();
    }

    loadFragment(fragment);
}

private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                toolbar.setTitle("Home | " +getString(R.string.app_name));
                fragment = new MainFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_news:
                toolbar.setTitle("News | " +getString(R.string.app_name));
                fragment = new NewsFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                return true;
            case R.id.navigation_setting:
                fragment = new SettingsFragment();
                loadFragment(fragment);
                toolbar.setTitle("Setting | " +getString(R.string.app_name));
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

    private void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

and here is my profil

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Activity_main.class);
    i.putExtra("Tab", 2);
    this.startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: What's your `onResume` code?

Answer (score 0):

And you can set whichever navigation item you'd like to be selected using **setSelectedItemId().**

```
else if(tabtoOpen == 2){
navigation.setSelectedItem(R.id.navigation_setting);
}
```